# Equation of the tangent plane to the surface $z=x^2+2y^3$ at the point $(1,1,3)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the equation of the tangent plane to the surface $z=x^2+2y^3$ at the point $(1,1,3)$. I think that it is $z=2x+6y-5$. Is that right?

Comment: it would be better if you showed us how you arrived at that answer

Comment: The answer is correct. Presumably you arrived at it through the right calculation.

Comment: oh thank god! I did it at the exam I don't even know how..my brain isn't working anymore...and something else...I was asked how f(x,Y)=3x^2+3y^2 look like, i had the following choices: a) hyperbolas, b) circles, c) parabolas d) straight lines... I chose circles, why? because I know that x^2+y^2 represents a circle, that was my guess, because honestly, I had no idea..so am I right?

Comment: **Cross-sections** of $z=3x^2+3y^2$ parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane are expanding circles. As to $z=3x^2+3y^2$, it is a three-dimensional **surface**.

Comment: yay! so I guess I got it correct...buuf thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal to the surface $x^2+2y^3-z=0$ is parallel the gradient: $(2x,6y^2,-1)$

At $(1,1,3)$, this is $(2,6,-1)$. The tangent plane is perpendicular to this vector. That is,
$$
(2,6,-1)\cdot(x,y,z)=2x+6y-z=5\tag{1}
$$
where $5$ is gotten by plugging $(1,1,3)$ into $2x+6y-z$.  $(1)$ is the equation of the tangent plane.